# Change App-Icon in App-Developer account before it is realeased

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, apple-developer

I have an app that is **not published** to the App-Store yet.
The thing is that I would like to change the app-icon for the release.
I know you can not change the icon of a running app in the app-store without submitting it a new version. But like I said, my app is not in the app-store.

Is there a way to change the icon?

This is a screenshot of my App-Developer Profile:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to change just the icon.

The icon is part of the binary. To change the icon you must therefore upload a new binary to iTunesConnect.

If your current version is already reviewed & accepted by Apple, why bother, the review process is quick; just takes a few days.

Unless you have a totally different icon, why not release the current version now and have the update ready in a few days.

To change the icon, simply drop new images (of appropriate sizes) in the AppIcon asset. This asset is typically in the app's Assets.xcassets folder; a blue folder icon in the project tree on the left.

The name of this asset corresponds to what's selected in your app's settings under: TARGETS > YourApp > General > App Icons and Launch Images > App Icons Source.

(After you change the icon it may not immediately show up on the device or simulator; I remember there were some issues in the past. Nothing is wrong though. If necessary, to force a refresh: Delete the app, reboot your device, and install the app again.)

BTW, did you know that an app can have one alternative icon that can be set after the app has been installed on user devices at run-time?

Comment: But if you have Realm in pods... I would prefer to avoid that build time, but unfortunately it's not possible.

Comment: I have not uploaded the binary and the new icon is completely different

Comment: @Chris If the binary is not uploaded yet, what is your issue?

Comment: @meaning-matters I can not change the icon. Or I dont know where :D

Comment: The icon comes from the binary you upload.  There is no other way/place to change it. Upload a binary containing the icon you want and get it approved.

Comment: @Chris I've added details.